# as.data.frame(x) vs data.frame(x) when coercing other objects into data frame?

Tags: r

I have executed the following script:

```
> results <- list()
> results$gp1 <- c(19, 18.5, 12)
> results$gp1 <- c(19, 17, 15)
> results$gp2 <- c(19, 18.5, 12)
> results$gp3 <- c(20, 19.5, 18)
> results
$`gp1`
[1] 19 17 15

$gp2
[1] 19.0 18.5 12.0

$gp3
[1] 20.0 19.5 18.0

> df_res <- data.frame(results)

> df_res_a <- as.data.frame(results)

> str(df_res)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ gp1: num  19 17 15
 $ gp2: num  19 18.5 12
 $ gp3: num  20 19.5 18

> str(df_res_a)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ gp1: num  19 17 15
 $ gp2: num  19 18.5 12
 $ gp3: num  20 19.5 18
```

It seems like both `as.data.frame(x)` and `data.frame(x)` work similarly when coercing the *list* into *data frame*. So which method should be used? Especially in case of large data volumes?

Comment: For large dataset, try `data.table::setDF`.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen
Thanks for the link ... but the only answer to my particular question I got from those answers is that `as.data.frame(x)` is faster. I want to know any other _reasons I should use the above method rather than `data.frame(x)` for coercing R objects into data frames_. I also want to know _why_ the former method is faster.

Comment: Fine, I reopened the question, under the assumption that you read the duplicate link end to end and really did not get an answer to your question.